# Can Singularity.gs be used without the command line?

Tags: singularitygs

I am a web designer and developer working on Windows. I have just started using SCSS which I run through Prepos App (therefore avoiding Ruby, command line, etc). I stumbled upon Singularitygs and loved how you flexible the grid system was and also the consistency of gutters in nesting (a problem in fluid grids).

Is there a way to use Singularitygs without the command line. I tried copying files into an existing project and compiling them through Prepos but I got a bunch of errors.

Answer (score 0):

Singularity 1.1.x requires a bit of Ruby code in order to operate, so you cannot use it if not compiling through Ruby and Compass. Singularity 1.2.x (should be released soon) will not have that Ruby requirement, but will require a compiler compatible with Sass 3.3. At the moment, only the Sass 3.3 prerelease is compatible with Sass 3.3, but once Sass 3.3 has a full release, most GUI apps should be updated to the latest version, at which point simply copying the files into your directory will work.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I did manage to get it compiled and had a little play with it. It worked to a certain degree, it created standard columns but couldn't do the varied width columns (really cool feature!). Looking forward to 1.2.x (any idea of a rough timescale?

Comment: We are trying to get this out for Sass 3.3 and will likely have something available around then but no public timeline is available.

Comment: @Snugug Ok. Keep up the great work. It's amazing. I've been looking for something that can nest columns with consistent gutters for ages.